# Does the "ass" in “smart-ass”, “lard ass” etc. mean "smart donkey" or "smart butt"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, american-english, slang, etymology

What's the literal meaning of ‘ass’ in expressions like ‘lard-ass’, ‘hard-ass’, ‘smart-ass’,… etc.?

Does ***ass*** here in such expressions mean ***donkey*** or ***butt***?

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to gain a better understanding of the usage of _-ass_ as an English learner. Am I correct? Is there another reason you want to know the literal meaning? You can [edit] your post to make that clearer.

Comment: [Titles are for titles, and questions belong in your question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4797/9161)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best definition I've found for "ass" in expressions of the form "X-ass" is from the Oxford English Dictionary:

> As the second element in compounds, forming adjectives with the sense ‘having or displaying the quality designated by the first element to an extreme or undesirable degree’

Etymologically, it is related to "ass" in the sense "butt".

Comment: Note: in  Britain the US "ass" becomes "arse".

Answer (score 4):

In American English, suffix **-ass** is an intensifier (in informal contexts). It can be tacked onto an adjective to intensify  either the speaker's approval or disapproval, or to underscore the speaker's stated opinion generally.

> That's a really bad-ass truck!

That sentence expresses the speaker's approval of a truck, probably one with large wheels and a powerful engine.  **bad** in slang is like "cool".

> Enough of your lame-ass excuses.

That statement expresses the speaker's disapproval of another person's poor excuses (for their action or inaction).

> That's a sloppy-ass paint job.  Couldn't you have been neater? Did you run out of masking tape or something?
>
> That's one tall-ass skyscraper!
>
> That's a big-ass mosquito bite you got there.

P.S. In **lard-ass**, **-ass** is not a suffix but the primary noun, as **lard** is not an adjective.  There  **ass** refers to the buttocks. The person is being called obese.